# How to commit empty folders to a Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial, directory, tortoisehg

I noticed that TortoiseHg doesn't commit empty folders.
How to fix that?

Comment: duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/81204/how-to-add-an-empty-folder-in-a-mercurial-project

Comment: superuser.com is a duplicate of stackoverflow.com. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is usually done by adding a hidden file in the folder (starting with a dot, like `.hidden`).

Comment: [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) suggests the name `.keep` for such files.

Answer (score 23):

Mercurial doesn't track empty folders.

If you really want an 'empty' folder in the repo, I'd suggest checking in a readme file in that folder explaining why it's empty/necessary to be in the repo, that way you can have a psuedo empty folder **and have documentation for why at the same time**.

Alternatively look at why you need this folder. Is it for you build process? Then maybe creating it should be part of the build process not version control.

Comment: the purpose of such folders is for interoperation with svn. my svn client requires that .svn\tmp exists

Comment: then probably a readme in the folder explaining that the folder is for svn interop is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

If you have a project with a build process it should create needed folders automatically when needed.